# Calculating smallest eigenvalues by real part using Arnoldi method

Tags: matrix, bugs, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

---

According to the documentation,

> `Eigenvalues[m,k]` gives the first `k` eigenvalues of `m` ...
>
> If they are numeric, eigenvalues are sorted in order of decreasing absolute value ...
>
> `Eigenvalues[m,-k]` gives the k that are smallest in absolute value."

What is the output of `Eigenvalues[m,-k]` if one specifies a method?

For example, consider

```
SeedRandom[1122];
mat = (# + Transpose[#]) &[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}]];
Eigenvalues[mat]
(* {-2.35168, 2.30789, 1.26678, -0.48013} *)

Eigenvalues[mat, 2, Method -> {"Arnoldi"}]
(* {-2.35168, 2.30789} *)

Eigenvalues[mat, -2, Method -> {"Arnoldi"}]
(* {1.26678, -0.48013} *)
```

This is exactly what I'd expect: the first two and last two eigenvalues, respectively, sorted in descending order by absolute value as usual.  But now consider

```
Eigenvalues[mat, 2, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]
(* {2.30789, 1.26678} *)

Eigenvalues[mat, -2, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]
(* {2.30789, 1.26678} *)
```

Why are the "first two" and "last two" eigenvalues the same?  I would have expected the last line to return `{-0.48013, -2.35168}` - the last two eigenvalues sorted in descending order by real part.

(Mathematica v 11.0.1.0 on Mac OS X Yosemite v 10.10.5.)

Comment: This does seem to directly contradict the documentation ... "`Eigenvalues[m,spec]` is always equivalent to `Take[Eigenvalues[m],spec]`."  I suggest letting [Wolfram Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/) know about this. Please let us know what they said.

Comment: Can you make the example reproducible?  Put in a `SeedRandom` at the beginning with a seed that results in the unexpected output.

Comment: @Szabolcs This error occurs regardless of the choice of random seed.  Also, this isn't *exactly* contradicting the documentation, because the statement you quoted does not apply to the case where one specifies a `Method`.  (Attempting `Take[Eigenvalues[mat, 
  Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}], -2]` returns `Eigenvalues::arall: Method -> Arnoldi cannot be used to compute more than 2 out of the 4 eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors.`)

Comment: Well, on the first try I got the expected result, and for no seed I tried did I get identical results for -2 and 2 (but there was overlap).

Comment: Maybe add your exact M version and OS as well, just in case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what I did exactly when I tried this, but if I copy your code now, as you wrote it, I do get identical results for 2 and -2.  It appears that "smallest" is taken to be "smallest positive" for some reason.  Try bigger matrices or using -1 instead of -2.  `-k` seems to return the `k` smallest positive eigenvalues.  BTW I also use M11.0.1 on OS X 10.12.1.

Comment: At least this observation gives you a workaround: also compute the largest positive eigenvalues of `-mat`.  You'd have to check if the eigenvalues are negative or positive though ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I suspect it's the nature of the Arnoldi algorithm - it's straightforward to target either the positive or the negative eigenvalues, but doing so actually involves two slightly different algorithms.  So once you've gotten all the positive ones, getting the negatives would require a completely separate calculation, and apparently Wolfram decided not to do that second calculation in its implementation of the Arnoldi algorithm.  I think they should modify their implementation to target negative eigenvalues if $k$ is negative, or at least clarify their documentation.

Comment: Anyway, I filed a report with Wolfram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wolfram Tech Support has confirmed that this is a bug and will work on fixing it.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the "Shift" option is not being properly set for the given "Criteria". Since we know that the largest eigenvalue by magnitude is 2.35168, we can assume that the smallest possible eigenvalue by real part will have a real part no smaller than -2.35168. So, using this as an approximate shift gives:

```
Eigenvalues[mat, -2, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria"->"RealPart", "Shift"->-2.5}]
```

> {-2.35168, -0.48013}

as desired.